# What are some good ways to visualize data in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-visualization, data-analysis

I got a data set with 12 predictors and 80000 samples. 
I'm wondering what are the good ways to visualize these data in R?
I've tried pairs() and cor() to see the correlation, but these are far from  sufficient.

To avoid my question being too broad. Here is some information about the data.
The predictors are used to predict y, which is either 0 or 1. So this is a classification problem.
I cannot put the data here since it's class material.
What I'm seeking is just some advice on how to start analyzing and exploring the data. This is my first time building models so I'm seeking advice from people who are experienced.

What I want to know is just "what would you do if you were given a data set like this and were asked to visualize the data and build models using the 12 predictors to predict y?"
I have enough information about how to build different classifiers and just want to know what should I do first with the data.

(Scaling the data is necessary and I will do this before training it.)

If this is still considered to be too broad, then let me know, I can delete or seeking helps elsewhere. This is already as specific as I can get without putting the real data up here. I know this is not like "how can I solve the bug in this snippet of code" kind of question. Just looking for some suggestions from people who's familiar with R and are experienced in analyzing data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad . You need to have a definite requirement in visualization. without any info or sample data on predictors it is very difficult to answer what visuals are you seeking. From what i understand ,  it is just about exploring data / or describing data - the following below may help

```
# create histograms for all continues variables 

library(plyr)
library(psych)
multi.hist(mpg[,sapply(mpg, is.numeric)])

# create bar plots for categorical variables

barplot(table('variable'),
  main="Title",
  xlab="Variable",
  ylab="Count",
  border="red",
  col="blue",
  density=10)

# looking at relation between continuous and discrete variables 

p <- ggplot(data, aes(cont.var1, cont.var2)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(. ~ 'categorical variable')


# fitting regression lines to scatter plots to explore relations between the 
# variables and with the dependent variables 

  ggplot(data, aes(x = cont.var1, y = cont.var2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red")

# Box plot to explore relation between categorical and continuous variables

  boxplot(Cont.var1~Cat.Var1, data, notch=TRUE, 
  col=(c("gold","darkgreen")),
  main="Title", xlab="Cat.var1")
```

These are some basic visuals used to explore / describe data.

Comment: Thank you so much, and for understanding what I want.